# Restrict Decimals Oracle Forms 10g

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle10g

I am using oracle forms 10g. I want to restrict the user not to enter more than 3 decimals in a field. The restriction should be done using the item property.

For example, 
form will raise an error when we enter character in date column. Similarly i want to raise an inbuilt exception for the decimals.

Comment: I dont want to write any pl/sql codes. I need to restrict the user at the time of entering itself.

Comment: Are you talking about the decimal point (`.`) itself, or digits that come after the decimal point (as in `.000`)?

Comment: digits coming after decimals.

Comment: Dont downvote, if you are not able to answer my questions. I clearly asked, is there any property or java implementation class is there to restrict more than 3 decimals.

Comment: I will downvote any question that is "unclear or not useful", as per the stackoverflow guidelines. It is not a reflection on you personally, it is not a personal attack, and it is certainly not because of an inability to answer your question - it is merely an opinion on the quality of the question as it is currently worded. Make your question clearer, and the downvote will be removed.

Comment: You were talking about decimal numbers before, but now you're talking about a date field? And what "character" are you talking about?

Comment: corrected the question.

Comment: (1) what datatype is the item - a date or a number? (2) please provide examples of *good* data and *bad* data for the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add following to somewhere .. 
`If Length(replace(input_var,'.','..'))-Length(input_var) > 3 then fail else pass end if;` .

Input_var is the variable that hold value entered by user.
I never worked on forms, but I think you must be able to add these kind of validation.

Cheers
V

Comment: I dont want to write any pl/sql codes. I need to restrict the user at the time of entering itself.

Comment: @Shankar, no-one really cares if you "don't want to" write any "pl/sql codes". If you're going to apply constraints like that on an acceptable solution you're going to have to give some kind of rationale.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain why you don't want to use a sql format mask or write pl/sql validation as this is kindof the expected way of doing things in Forms.

I am sure you could do the same by using something like java.text.DecimalFormat or by using string functions in java but this goes against the normal way of doing things in Oracle Forms.

Comment: Because, if i add a format mask, if there is no decimal for a value, it will show as 99.000. here i dont want to show 000 to the users. And i need to stop at the time of entering. i dont want to stop during navigation from the field.